# JITing html template files

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, jit

Many people use jinja template rendering for their web base apps.

A high percentage of apps have a few templates but when the app gets popular,  templates will be processed many times.

I wanna to know that is processing the templates a bottleneck as app gets more hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jinja2` is robust enough to render templates responsively but the problem is seen when you have a heavy/blocking tasks to process (requesting database, bulk operations ..) before passing variables to `jinja2` to render templates.

so with a good application design comes a good performance.

- add **caching support**, use 3rd `Flask` extensions like `flask-caching`
- use **Task Queues apps** (like `redis` or `celery` ..) to handle **asynchronously** in  background a long-running jobs that would dramatically reduce the performance of an HTTP response
- use an **HTTP accelerator** like `varnish`